# show/ hide detail on jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

i want to hide/show a table in a detail section depending on the length of the table, How can I do that ?
how can i pass the length of the table to the global report parameter untill i can use it in a condition to show/hide the detail ?

i try to send the variable as a parameter from the code but its not a good practice when the number of table grow
so i want to get the variable from the inside of report.

`<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{NumAP}!=null && $F{NumAP}.isEmpty()]]></printWhenExpression>`